# How to display the source files' names on the left hand side Chrome developer tools Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

At the moment, they appear on the right hand side. It's hardly readable.
This would greatly improve readability and productivity in debugging:
[image]

Comment: You know about breakpoints and the `debugger;` statement?

Comment: @dev-null: yes, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To get what you want, you need to create a custom DevTools Theme and build an extension for it. That theme would then target the display and modify as-needed.

2) Moving it to the left would then get in the way of running commands and viewing the actual data output. So, a very unlikely core change even for an option. It isn't really there for legibility, but supplemental information about where an entry in the console came from.